# Track CSS Framework Usage

Tags: css, metrics

So I work on a project that has created a small UI framework that allows other projects/organizations to reference our stylesheet to build web apps/sites that have a similar look and feel to our main project. We'd like to track a couple of things. 1) how many applications/sites reference our stylesheet and 2) if possible, how many page hits each one of those sites/applications receive.

We currently have a few tools collecting metrics on our main project (such as Google Analytics), but I'm unaware of any way to track how many times a CSS file is referenced out in the wild.

Any tips or creative solutions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: unless people use your CSS from your own domain or CDN, there is not much you can do without using shady practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution I can think of is to serve your css library from a CDN. you will have the possibility to collect data when a client requests your resources from there.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we're going to end up doing. Thanks.